# Flutter default text fallback not working on android. Works on ios and web

Tags: android, flutter, textstyle

I have a Flutter app that uses the font "ArchitypeRenner". The app also supports multiple languages. For some languages like Belarusian (Беларуская), I understand that the font "ArchitypeRenner" does not provide support. The problem is, on iOS and web (canvas kit) the text is somehow displayed properly (I think the fallback font is used somehow) , but on android the text is rendered with some parts shown as "X". When I use the font "Roboto" there are no issues in android.

[image]